# python How to remove None on my method call?

Tags: python, nonetype

I have call this method but when the data return, it returns a None below the data. How can i prevent that ?

```
def weather_Connection(interval,apikey):


    print print_forecast('Choa Chu Kang',get_response('/forecast/apikey/1.394557,103.746396'))
    print print_forecast('Yishun',get_response('/forecast/apikey/1.429463,103.84022'))
    print print_forecast('Redhill',get_response('/forecast/apikey/1.289732,103.81675'))
    print print_forecast('Jalan Besar',get_response('/forecast/apikey/1.312426,103.854317'))
    print print_forecast('Jurong West',get_response('/forecast/apikey/1.352008,103.698599'))
    print print_forecast('Tampines',get_response('/forecast/apikey/1.353092,103.945229'))
```

Data return in this way

```
cloudCover : 0.75
dewPoint: 24.87
humidity: 80.00
icon : partly-cloudy-night
ozone : 276.67
precipIntensity : 0
precipProbability : 0
pressure : 1009.61
summary : Dry and Mostly Cloudy
temperature: 28.56
visibility : 6.21
windBearing : 127
windSpeed : 4.57
psiAverage : 20
latitude : 1.394557
longitude : 103.746396
location : Choa Chu Kang
None
```

Answer (score 6):

You are printing the return value of your function, **and** printing inside the function. Remove the `print` statement you are using to print the return value of the call.

Where you do:

```
print weather_Connection(interval, api_key)
```

remove the `print`:

```
weather_Connection(interval, api_key)
```

A function in Python *always* has a return value, even if you do not use a `return` statement, defaulting to `None`:

```
>>> def foo(): pass  # noop function
... 
>>> print foo()
None
```

The alternative is to *not* use `print` in your function, but return a string instead:

```
def weather_Connection(interval,apikey):
    result = [
        print_forecast('Choa Chu Kang',get_response('/forecast/apikey/1.394557,103.746396')),
        print_forecast('Yishun',get_response('/forecast/apikey/1.429463,103.84022')),
        print_forecast('Redhill',get_response('/forecast/apikey/1.289732,103.81675')),
        print_forecast('Jalan Besar',get_response('/forecast/apikey/1.312426,103.854317')),
        print_forecast('Jurong West',get_response('/forecast/apikey/1.352008,103.698599')),
        print_forecast('Tampines',get_response('/forecast/apikey/1.353092,103.945229')),
    ]
    return '\n'.join(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `print()` call, the function is returning `None`.

The default return value of a function is `None` in python. If you're printing inside a function and not returning anything from it then there's no need of `print()` when calling the function.

**Demo:**

```
>>> def func():
...     print ("foo")
...     
>>> print(func())
foo
None
>>> func()      #works fine without `print()`
foo
```